# Android - Dynamic marker in GoogleMaps v2 API

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I am showing a marker to show user's position in GoogleMaps v2 api in Android, and I am also showing where the user is looking at (kind of like the Google Map app does with the blue dot and the arrow but with custom drawing).

For  this I use a GroundOverlay item and a Thread that redraws the Bitmap:

```
positionOverlayThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!stopPositionOverlayThread)
            {
                // We update the bitmap object by re-drawing it
                updatePositionBitmap();
                // We set it as the icon for the overlay
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        BitmapDescriptor posDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(positionBitmap);
                        _mPositionOverlay.setImage(posDescriptor);
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            LogException(e);
                        }                 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

It seems that this causes a memory leak and I suspect it's coming from the new BitmapDescritor I create every time. Am I not supposed to recycle it on every pass? But I cannot find any way of doing so.

**EDIT**: I found [this  thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5061) on gmaps-api but no resolution

Comment: _mPositionOverlay.setImage(posDescriptor); Do this in main thread.

Comment: how does this help with memory management? This is already done - i simplified the code and deleted a runOnUiThread()

Comment: U have not mentioned where u get the idea its leaking memory? Most of google map items  should be updated in main thread

Comment: Because the heap grows wild which doesn't happen when I comment the two lines where the new descriptor is created and the new Image set, and at some point I get OutOfMemoryError at the line where the new BitmapDescriptor is created

Comment: post more code, enable largeHeap in android manifest and update map items in main thread or u will get exception

Comment: u should simply use Marker object update its location on onlocationChange instead of making a bitmap again and again

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect how I do this in a runOnUiThread  and still get the memory problem. Thanks for trying to help but your last comment is off topic - I am updating the bitmap as the user moves his phone to reflect the direction he is looking at as the blue arrow does in GoogleMaps, not just showing his location

Comment: i see, Turn the largeHeap on in android manifest and try. Also try to reduce the size of bitmap you are using. Not sure where u are getting largeHeap? post some log perhaps?

Comment: Thanks but again I am not looking to extend the heap, I am looking to avoid the memory leak... extending the heap or reducing the bitmap size will just make it last longer before it crashes not fix the underlying problem